# Assigning one variable the value of another in bash

Tags: bash, vi

I am using a switcher that exports environmental variables based upon which machine is being used. One of the variables that gets exported is ems_1 .
Now, in my start.bash script, I am trying to assign a variable called provider with the value ems_1 has.

```
export provider = ems_1
```

Doesn't work . Any suggestions ?

Comment: `provider=$ems_1`. No spaces around the `=` sign. And remove `export` (unless you really want to export it).

Comment: Thanks!. that worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
export provider=$ems_1
```

- You need to reference variables using the `$` sign.
- `variable=value`
  cannot have spaces in-between.